# Access 2013 - Setting multiple font colors in field on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm fairly certain what I'm looking for can't be done. I have a form that users will input a list of data into. The data will be a list of steps that need to be completed. Currently the font is black, but they would like specify sentences to change color such as red, black, and green. The only thing I could think of would be conditional formatting, but that would affect all of the text and not just small portion of it.

Like I said, I don't think it's doable, but I figured I'd ask and see if anyone has tried this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Access 2007 you don't need a separate control. You need a Memo (Long Text) field behind the control, and set the `TextFormat` property of the field and the text box to `RichText`.

See [Insert or add a rich text field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630)

It supports a subset of HTML, including font colors. Access provides the functionality to format the text, both in the ribbon and in a popup menu (that is also available in the Access runtime).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a rich text control. Either the color formatting can be applied by use of the GUI, or you can write the color coding yourself with VBA.

It depends a bit on how the data is intended to be edited.